# ReactJS filter API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm using an API to get an array of Objects.
Each object has a lot of data, I want to filter this data to just grab the data I need so I can display it on a React-Table.

```js
export default class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
  const string = 'http://localhost:8000/issues/assigned/mike';
  fetch(string)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => this.setState(myJson));
  console.log(this.state)
}

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
        this.fetchData()
    }
  }

render() {
    return this.state.issues? (
      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={this.state.issues} />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
         Loading ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The JSON file I'm receiving from the API: [JSON DATA NEST](https://jsonblob.com/8e148758-4f83-11e8-9df1-01379195c3a0)

For the example there is only one object, I'm receiving 50 object with the exact same nesting, I'm looking forward to extract a few properties (for example, `data.issues[0].fields.timespent` ) so I can pass this data into my react-table and create a row for each "issue".

Comment: What data are you trying to filter for?

Comment: Hi Colin, this is the data which i receive from the API, 
https://jsonblob.com/8e148758-4f83-11e8-9df1-01379195c3a0
For the example purpose the "Issues" only has one object.. i'm looking to filter some info, for example, timespent, description...

Answer (score 1):

`setState` function does not immediately update a component but you can use a callback function `setState(updater[, callback])` to get your state right after it was updated.

Regarding data filtering, you can use `.map()` or `.filter()` function to transform or filter your collection after a response was converted to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter data that you need and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to map this data to appropriate model.